# best ways to store and play video files using google app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am new to Google app engine, we are building a content management system using app engine. Users update the video files from the browser, it should then be saved in the data store and then retrieved on demand. What would be the best place to save this in terms of scalability and cost?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage I guess. Any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of Google Cloud Platform, Cloud Storage would be the place to store and serve large binaries. You could use another storage vendor to store the content, but then if you do any processing on that data, your egress charges might outweigh any savings you get hosting it elsewhere.

Your milage may vary, I would test on Google Cloud Storage and see what you get. You can also use the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to do some planning for cost.

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks a lot for the helpful information . I am currently trying out blob store. How is it different from google cloud storage?

Comment: Well, it's not deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api.  Basically as we've expanded the capabilities of Google Cloud Storage, we've deprecated the API.

Comment: so does it mean its better to use cloud storage api rather than blob store api to build new applications?